# How to change tab on button click from another tab in Flutter App

Tags: android, flutter, dart

After the form was filled, the tab did not change and it was expected to automatically switch back to the home page.

Comment: Can you include your snippet what you've done so far, what is issue. you can check more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you want to fill up a textfield, and then close button and data will show in previous page?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use setState? Changing a variable does not cause a rebuild. SetState needs to be called in order to have your StatefulWidget's build method re-run, with the changed variables taken into account.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html